# Typing symbols directly instead of diacritics

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, typing

After reinstalling my Mac OS X 10.6.6 typing special characters like these `" ~` and more does not directly insert them into the text, but waits for the next character to be pressed. If these two combines well, such as the `quote` and `a` to `ä`, they mix together. I find this very annoying. Is here any way to fix this, so the characters are inserted immediately? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked what language your keyboard is set to? This is standard on Swedish keyboards, for example.

Comment: Typing space after this symbols will print just the symbol, but I'd go down @victoriah's route: check your locale settings.

Comment: @victoriah this happens both for Input Source `US International` and my national language. Formats are set to `United States (Computer)`. @Nerdling I know, but it's slowing me down too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "dead keys", though MacOS calls it something else.  On both *nix and MacOS, it's triggered by choosing an international keyboard layout.

Go to "System Preferences", "Language & Text", select the US keyboard layout and *unselect* the "US International - PC" layout.